# Data is not showing by using recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Data is not showing on android screen and I'm not getting any error in LogCat either. In LogCat it is displaying the data but its not displaying on screen. I searched many thing but didn't got any answer for this. I'm using `RecyclerView` to show the data.

Here is my code - `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    gAdapter = new GetJobDetailsAdapter(detailsJob);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView .setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
     String url = "url"

    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(SecondActivity.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, data, status);
            if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {

                String StringData = "" + data;
                try {
                    JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
                    int len = rootArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                        JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);

                        GetJobDetailsJobs b1 = new GetJobDetailsJobs();
                        b1.About_Company = json.optString("Req_Additional_Details");
                        b1.Designation = json.optString("Req_Designation_Role");
                        b1.Eligibility = json.optString("JobTitle");
                        b1.JobLocation = json.optString("Job_Location");
                        b1.JobDescription=json.optString("Req_Project_Desc");


                        detailsJob.add(b1);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And below is my Adapter code:

```
public class GetJobDetailsAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GetJobDetailsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    public List<GetJobDetailsJobs> detailsJob;
    public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView About_Company,Designation,Eligibility,JobLocation,JobDescription,KeySkills,EventDate,EventLocation,Salary,Comp_Name;
        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            About_Company=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.About_Company);
            Designation=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Designation);
            Eligibility=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Eligibility);
            JobLocation=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.JobLocation);
            JobDescription=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.JobDescription);
            KeySkills=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.KeySkills);
            EventDate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.EventDate);
            EventLocation=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.EventLocation);
            Salary=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Salary);
            Comp_Name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Comp_Name);
        }
    }
    public GetJobDetailsAdapter(List<GetJobDetailsJobs>detailsJob){
        this.detailsJob=detailsJob;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.jobdetails, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GetJobDetailsJobs b1 = detailsJob.get(position);
        holder.About_Company.setText(b1.getAbout_Company());
        holder.Designation.setText(b1.getDesignation());
        holder.Eligibility.setText(b1.getEligibility());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return detailsJob.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add full adapter code

Comment: Did you called `notifyDataSetChanged()` after adding items to the list?

Comment: please add `recyclerview.setadapter(gAdapter)` after `detailsJob.add(b1);` in `callback` method

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting adapter to recyclerview in your code. "recyclerView.setAdapter(gAdapter)" set it either in onCreate or in Ajax callback .

```
   recyclerView.setAdapter(gAdapter)
```

After you get the jobDetails from Ajax callback you have to set it to adapter.

```
gAdapter.setJobDetailsAdapterData(your_jobs_data);
```

Then it will set the data and call notifyDataSetChanged.

**Adapter:**
This should be a setJobDetailsAdapter.

```
public void setJobDetailsAdapterData(List<GetJobDetailsJobs>detailsJob){
        this.detailsJob=detailsJob;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` in the adapter constructor doesn't do you any good. you should call it after adding items to the list.

Comment: @Boss yes, it should be a method where i have to setData and then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @HourGlass Then please edit your answer, so that i can remove the downvote.

Comment: Actually you don't need to write a method inside the adapter, you just update the same list which you previously passed to the adapter constructor and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. then it will work.

Comment: Either way is fine. call notifyDataSetChanged inside adapter or set the data to adpater method and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged from mainactivity @Boss

Answer (score 0):

You forgot two things 1. set your adapter 2. and call the notifyDataSetChanged , after adding new element

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        gAdapter = new GetJobDetailsAdapter(detailsJob);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView .setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
       recyclerView.setAdapter(gAdapter) ; //You must set your adapter
         String url = "url"

        AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(SecondActivity.this);
        mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {
                super.callback(url, data, status);
                if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {

                    String StringData = "" + data;
                    try {
                        JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
                        int len = rootArray.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                            JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);

                            GetJobDetailsJobs b1 = new GetJobDetailsJobs();
                            b1.About_Company = json.optString("Req_Additional_Details");
                            b1.Designation = json.optString("Req_Designation_Role");
                            b1.Eligibility = json.optString("JobTitle");
                            b1.JobLocation = json.optString("Job_Location");
                            b1.JobDescription=json.optString("Req_Project_Desc");


                            detailsJob.add(b1);

                            gAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //call notifyDataSetChanged , every time you add an item
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `RecyclerView` doesn't contain a method `notifyDataSetChanged()`. you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: yes got it...added recyclerview.setadapter(gAdapter) after detailsJob.add(b1);

Comment: @Boss , sorry my bad , I was supposed to do it . I am editing my answer . Thanks for pointing it out .

Comment: @shuvro one more point, it should be better if you call `gAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` just after the loop. right? for better performance.

Comment: @tiya if this solution worked for you , please accept this answer.